# How do I monitor the status of an C# windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, monitoring, health-monitoring

Lets say I have a Windows application named `app.exe`, written in C# (Windows Forms), running *unattended* under any Windows OS (XP to 8).

I would like to monitor the status of the app:

- Is the app still running or has it crashed
- Has the app run into an internal error state

My idea is to set up a scheduled task in Windows (using the Task Scheduler) to run a Windows Console application, `monitor.exe`, every 15 minutes.
The monitor app will send an email with the status of `app.exe`.

What I have not been able to figure out:

- How do I find out if `app.exe` is still running?
- How do I access an internal variable in `app.exe` from `monitor.exe`?

One idea was to set up a timer in `app.exe` which will write the internal status out to a file, and have `monitor.exe` read and evaluate that file every 15 minutes. But that does not appear very elegant to me (however it would work).

Do you have a better, best practise, approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more complicated solution, which you could add a monitor layer and a service layer in `app.exe`. The monitor layer is responsible for collecting internal variables status, and the service layer is responsible for providing internal status to whom issuing a `GetStatus` request.

Whenever `monitor.exe` is executed, it issues a `GetStatus` service request to `app.exe`, and get the response of what is going on from inside of `app.exe`.

The disadvantage is that you must create a connection between `app.exe` and `monitor.exe`, and the latter must know the service port of all app.exe which deployed on the local machine.

Comment: Hi, ssett, I like that idea. Do you mean something like a named pipe? Where you can have a client and server exchanging messages locally?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, named pipe is fine. The detailed implementation could be vary.

Comment: I ended up using named pipes for inter process communication (IPC). That concept was totally new for me, so thanks @ssett for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Performance counters are perfect for this.  I have several .Net applications that use a `PerformanceCounterType.ElapsedTime` counter and set the "last checked time" in the main loop.

I then monitor this counter with a centralized monitoring and notification system.  (We use SolarWinds at work)  If I expect something to run every minute and the counter exceeds 5 minutes, the alerts are set to go off.

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail from `app.exe` in a timer for status and if you have not received mail last 15 minutes this means you app crashed or closed.

Or create try/catch for your operations for collecting informations abaut crashes and send them with e-mail that includes current status too.

Comment: Hi, TC Alper Tokcan, I would like to implement the email sending in monitor.exe only, since I want to reuse the monitor.exe for other app.exes. Thus I like to know who to access the status of app.exe. Thank you! (:

Comment: @Sebastian I think only way for `app.exe` to `monitor.exe` communicating is saving a file from `app.exe` that have some information about status and reading it from `monitor.exe` :)